# Redirect stdin to read from file while keeping stdin as input in Bash

Tags: bash, file-io

I try to build a program which asks the user for inputs all the time. To test this programm (Xtreme programming) it is a big effort to type all those inputs at every test. So I decided to write the inputs down in a file and redirect stdin to that file like

`cat inputs.txt | ./myprogram` or `./myprogram < inputs.txt`.

This works fine so far, but I wanted to be able to type other inputs myself after the file has reached EOF (also before doesn't really matter), so inputs of the first part of the program (which I already know is working) will be written automatically and I can type in the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat` can read from multiple files, including standard input using the name "-":

```
cat inputs.txt - | ./myprogram
```

---

If `./myprogram` needs to run in the current shell, things get trickier. You can use process substitution:

```
./myprogram < <(cat inputs.txt -)
```

or a named pipe:

```
mkfifo p
cat inputs.txt - > p &
./myprogram < p
```

Comment: Awesome, if the program runs in the current shell or not isn't a problem for me, totally forgot the minus operator of cat. thanks